# BigQuery load failing with backend error on nearly every load attempt

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying in vain for nearly two days to load in two large datasets, each of which are ~30GB/s and split into 50 uncompressed ~600MB files each, all coming from a bucket. Almost always the jobs fail with "internal" or "backend" error.

I have tried submitting with a wild card (as in *csv) and I have also tried the individual files.

On the rare occasion the load job does not fail within a few minutes, it will eventually die after 6 or 7 hours.

I have split the files and made them uncompressed to help with load times, would this be causing an issue? I did have a compressed version load successfully after about 7 hours yesterday, but so far I have only been able to load a single 350 MB CSV uncompressed from the bucket.

Here is an example:

Errors:
Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem. (error code: backendError)
Job ID  bvedemo:bquijob_64ebebf1_1532f1b3c4f

Backend error would imply something is happening at Google, but I must be doing something wrong to have it fail this often!

Answer (score 2):

Lesson of the day: do not try to load data from a nearline bucket into BigQuery.

I moved the data into a standard bucket, reloaded from there and 65GB of data loaded in less than 1 minute.

Comment: Looks like a problem on the Google's side. Loading data from Nearline bucket is supported and should not fail. Have you tried to open a support ticket with Google Support and provide them with your load job id?

Comment: Nope, bronze support only. This is a trial more than anything else.